# Combining images from folder two by two in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

Combining images from folder two by two in imagemagick.

Hi there,

I have a folder with images such as this list:

- image1.jpg
- image2.jpg
- image3.jpg
- alphaplupp.jpg
- kj56.jpg
- rumiba54.jpg

How can I use imagemagick to merge all of them horizontally like so:

- image1.jpg+image2.jpg
- image3.jpg+alphaplupp.jpg
- kj56.jpg+rumiba54.jpg

Vesa

Comment: Windows or a real OS with `bash`? What should the output files be called? Are the images the same size?

Comment: Hi there. I am unfortunately stuck with Windows at the moment. The output files could be called image1-image2.jpg for example. No, the images are not the same size. When they are combined horizontally they should be the same height but the same width is not necessary.

Comment: What do you mean *"they should be the same height"*? Are they the same height or are you also expecting this script to make them the same?

Comment: I mean in the output the 2 images should be made the same height. Same width does not matter. The 2 input images may be of different height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't normally write BATCH files, but this works for me - there may be better ways of doing it...

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Combine images side-side pairwise from the current directory using ImageMagick
REM Images are assumed to be named file1.jpg, file2.jpg, file3.jpg
REM Images are resized to a common height, as specified on next line
SET HEIGHT=500
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%A in (1,2,1000) DO (
   SET /A "B=%%A+1"
   SET _f1=file%%A.jpg
   SET _f2=file!B!.jpg
   IF NOT EXIST "!_f1!" GOTO BRK
   IF NOT EXIST "!_f2!" GOTO BRK
   SET _result=joined%%A_!B!.jpg
   ECHO Joining !_f1! and !_f2! into !_result!
   convert "!_f1!" "!_f2!" -resize x%HEIGHT% +append "!_result!"
)
:BRK
```

I have no idea how you do a `while` loop in Windows, so I am using a `for` loop. I am guessing you have no more than 1,000 files. If you do, increase the 1,000 on the third line. You can change the common height to which images are resized at the top of the script.

In general, if you want to lay out two images whose names do not fit your `fileXYZ.jpg` naming standard, let's say they are, `imageA.jpg` and `imageB.jpg`, beside each other and resize both to 500 pixels tall and save as `result.jpg` you would do

```
convert imageA.jpg imageB.jpg -resize x500 result.jpg
```

Comment: So, that's a good starter and I think the question is 75% solved. However the output images do not have the same height. Also, some of the file names in the folder have a different naming scheme, let's say alphadkg.jpg, knj123.jpg and I wonder how to join all files accordingly regardless of file name?

Comment: I have added a **HEIGHT** variable and all images are sized to that height before being combined.

Comment: The prospect of joining files with wildly different names doesn't sit well with this approach - how can I possibly know that `monkeybrains357.jpg` needs to be joined with `freddyfox53.jpg`?

Comment: I see. Actually, at the moment, I am pretty content with the situation. If there is anything I can do for you, let me know : ) Thanks a lot for writing the batch script!